# Scrapy a hidden content in source code

Tags: python, scrapy

Hi I want to crawl some contents which I cannot see from the page source code while they are there by seeing the page. 
A example site : https://bangumi.bilibili.com/anime/index#p=1&v=1&area=2&stat=0&y=0&q=0&tag=&t=1&sort=0
(I want to get the anime info)

Could anyone can give me any hint to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example of data which do you want to extract from this page? This site uses Js, e.g [one of the json file](https://bangumi.bilibili.com/web_api/season/index_global?page=1&page_size=20&version=1&is_finish=0&start_year=0&tag_id=&index_type=1&index_sort=0&area=2&quarter=0) that page uses for populating its content. Try to study `Network` tab in your browser and you can detect other requests.

Comment: Thank you! This json file is exact what I want, more precisely, info of "title" "url".  I will take a look at the network tab and want to know if there is any way to pull the info from all pages automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all info on this page populated via json you can make a direct request to json endpoint and if you use `for loop` you can extract all desired info.

```
import scrapy
import json


class BiliSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "bilispider"

    def start_requests(self):
        url = "https://bangumi.bilibili.com/web_api/season/index_global?page={}&page_size=20&version=1&is_finish=0&start_year=0&tag_id=&index_type=1&index_sort=0&area=2&quarter=0"
        for i in range(1, 99):
            yield scrapy.Request(url.format(i), callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        res = json.loads(response.text)
        item = dict()
        for el in res['result']['list']:
            item['title'] = el['title']
            item['url'] = el['url']
            yield item

# Output:
# 2017-07-05 09:11:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bangumi.bilibili.com/web_api/season/index_glo
# bal?page=96&page_size=20&version=1&is_finish=0&start_year=0&tag_id=&index_type=1&index_sort=0&area=2&quarter=0>
# {'title': '激斗战车（国语）', 'url': 'http://bangumi.bilibili.com/anime/5380'}
# 2017-07-05 09:11:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bangumi.bilibili.com/web_api/season/index_glo
# bal?page=96&page_size=20&version=1&is_finish=0&start_year=0&tag_id=&index_type=1&index_sort=0&area=2&quarter=0>
# {'title': '银河漂流VIFAM', 'url': 'http://bangumi.bilibili.com/anime/2437'}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the website loads the content dynamically, therefor you need to render the page completely (which also means you have to parse the JavaScript).
Due to that fact, you should consider using an headless browser.

Comment: Thank you, I will look up some info about how to get the javascript result.